# Turn $\exists z \forall y[p(y) \land r(z,y)] \to \exists y r(x,y)$ into CNF

Tags: logic, predicate-logic

Turn $\exists z \forall y[p(y) \land r(z,y)] \to \exists y r(x,y)$ into CNF.

What i tried:
$\exists z \forall y[p(y) \land r(z,y)] \to \exists y r(x,y) \equiv \lnot(\exists z \forall y[p(y) \land r(z,y)]) \lor \exists y r(x,y) \equiv \forall z \lnot (\forall y [p(y) \land r(z,y)])\lor\exists yr(x,y) \equiv \forall z \exists y[\lnot p(y)\lor \lnot r(z,y)]\lor \exists yr(x,y) \equiv \forall z \exists y \exists l[\lnot p(y) \lor\lnot r(z,y)\lor r(x,l)]$

After skolemization:
$\forall z [\lnot p(sk_1(z)) \lor\lnot r(z,sk_1(z))\lor r(x,sk_2(z))]$

And if i put l infront it would be 
$\forall z [\lnot p(sk_1(z)) \lor\lnot r(z,sk_1(z))\lor r(x,c_1)]$

Is it obligatory to skolemize for cnf ? Are my steps correct till now ?

Im sorry I used equiv for for logical equivalence i didnt find the symbol i should use.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your steps are all correct!

The body of your formula is in CNF, but probably they want you to indeed skolemize and drop the universal quantifier.

Note that if you *first* pull out the second existential, you can avoid having to use one of the functions when skolemizing:

$\forall z \exists y[\lnot p(y)\lor \lnot r(z,y)]\lor \exists y \ r(x,y) \Leftrightarrow$

$\forall z \exists y[\lnot p(y)\lor \lnot r(z,y)]\lor \exists l \ r(x,l) \Leftrightarrow$

$\exists l (\forall z \exists y[\lnot p(y)\lor \lnot r(z,y)]\lor r(x,l))\Leftrightarrow$

$\exists l \forall z \exists y[\lnot p(y)\lor \lnot r(z,y)\lor r(x,l)]$

Skolemizing this, you get:

$\lnot p(f(z))\lor \lnot r(z,f(z))\lor r(x,c)$

Comment: thanks indeed a typo, can i try skolemize it and you tell if its correct ? btw i thought skolemization drops existential quantifiers ???

Comment: @asddf Yes, you drop the existentials too, but you have to fill in constants or some function, while universals just get dropped without any changes ... sorry to confuse you!

Comment: @asddf Just saw your skolemization:  since the existentials come *after* the universal, you need to use functions.  I'll add to my post ...

Comment: i edited it can you take a look ?

Comment: @asddf Yes, that all looks good ... and now you can just drop the universal completely!

Comment: @asddf You're welcome!  P.s. use \Leftrightarrow for the logical equivalence symbol